# Dokku, RoR and Mongo DB: Unauthorized not authorized on db to execute command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, dokku

I have been struggling with this issue for days, i am able to authenticate with the mongo shell.

But when i access it my application from the browser, i got the above mentioned error.

Ruby on rails logs:

> 2016-07-05T04:29:34.415943099Z app[web.1]: MONGODB | xx.xx.xx.xx:4121
> | [db].count | STARTED | {"count"=>"listings", "query"=>{}}
>
> 2016-07-05T04:29:34.418337913Z app[web.1]: MONGODB | xx.xx.xx.xx:4121
> | [db].count | FAILED | not authorized on [db] to execute command {
> count: "listings", query: {} } (13) | 0.0021065790000000004s

Background
Hosting on Digital Ocean, with the One-Click Deployment of Dokku.

Dokku Version : 0.6.4
MongoDB : 3.2.6
Ruby: 2.2.4
Rails 4.2.6

I have added user (with DbOwner) to MongoDB and the same to mongoid.yml.

Here is `mongoid.yml`

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: sample
      hosts:
        - ip:4121
      user: "user"
      password: "password"
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution for this and i thought i will close the loop on this and save someone a couple of hours/days trying to figure this out.

Basically, the one-click from digital ocean **DOES** work!

But you need the following in your mongoid.yml, add the URI in and remove the database, user and password.

To generate the URI, do the following in your ssh terminal console:

```
dokku mongo:info <<db name>>
```

Update the uri value with what was displayed on screen.

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <<URI>>
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but a general piece of advice is, don't go for one click deployment of dokku. Spin up a droplet and install dokku manually, it doesn't take too much of effort also.

One click deployment creates unwanted config errors. Its suggested to go with that approach if you want to do some RnD and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

dokku one click images works normally all the time, there is no problems

have you installed the mongodb plugin of dokku?
https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-mongodb-plugin

if you already instaled the plugin, you don't upload the yml  file, you then just need to run the link command in your server

```
mongodb:create <app>
mongodb:link <app> <database>
```

or you can create and link in the same command

```
mongodb:create <app> <database>
```

Comment: Hmm the .yml file is not needed?